# Disable CORS in Brave Browser

Tags: brave, brave-browser

Recently I've switched from Safari to Brave *([Safari has a horrible bug - when ever you open dev tools, you get logged out from every site](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253248182))*, and I'm trying to run it in CORS disabled mode.

I've tried modifying the command I would usually use for Chrome, but every attempt was unsuccessful:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --user-data-dir="/var/tmp/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

My local Angular app is connecting to couple of remote servers and all requests get blocked unless I disable CORS - and no I can't make any changes on the servers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

here is what work for me, I use OSX this way you don't need to close other opened brave apps.

```
open -n -a /Applications/Brave\ Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave\ Browser --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/brave_dev_sess_1" --disable-web-security
```

Answer (score 4):

Because Brave is a version of the Chromium Web Browser, the same methods that work for Chrome will work for Brave. See the post: [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

The answer that specifically worked for me was <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>

```
brave.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security "enter url here"
```